# .NET Core application, extension method not found

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've got a very simple application with the following .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>MyTestProject</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The code is:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true);
IConfigurationRoot root = builder.Build();
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, { root["weather"] } world!");
```

The error I get is:

> error CS1061: 'ConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a method named 'AddJsonFile' (...)

I found the example here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

If i remove the call to AddJsonFile, the application works. That is, it's the extension method that fails to be loaded:

```
IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
```

#### Edit 1

The fix is simple, tnx to [Mathias R.Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) and [Rand Random](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2598770/rand-random).
Just add a reference to Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.
That was also documented in the basic example in the docs.

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="7.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="7.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="7.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="7.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What can be confusing in extension methods is that if you don't reference the assembly that provides the extension method, you can have a "partially working class".
What I still find strange is that Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration is not required anymore, it works even if you remove it.
But that is the only one mentioned in the ConfigurationBuilder class docs.

[image: ConfigurationBuilder class docs]

Comment: Sounds like you want to `dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`

Comment: as is mentioned on `For more information, see Configuration - basic example` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration#basic-example

Comment: That example demonstrates the class. It's not a complete runnable program.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i wrote the solution in my Edit 1, if you want to post as a solution i will accept it; maybe you can elaborate a bit on extension methods in different assemblies and documentation not mentioning them ... :-)

Comment: [AddJsonFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.jsonconfigurationextensions.addjsonfile?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) has namespace: `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`, and [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.json?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) does not have `AddJsonFile`, so some explanation would be nice.... 

Comment: FYI you mentioned `... Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration is not required anymore...` this is because the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` package defines a dependency to the other package and it will be automatically resolved, you don't need to manually add all dependent packages - you may find an explanation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution `Any time a package is installed or reinstalled, which includes being installed as part of a restore process, NuGet also installs any additional packages on which that first package depends.`

Comment: as you can see here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/#dependencies-body-tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up the documentation for [the `AddJsonFile()` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.jsonconfigurationextensions.addjsonfile?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), you'll see it's contained in the following package:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json v7.0.0
```

So adding said package reference to your project should allow you to restore the required dependency:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
```

Comment: Yes but... in this page I couldn't find any reference to Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

Comment: Right under "Definition" at the top of the page :)